# Researching chips and sourcing components

Tags: components, identification, source

How do you research and select a chip for a given task? Are there some formalised and centralised databases I should be using? This would go equally for pre-assembled modules.

Following on, where should I be looking to source small batches (1-10) of said components for prototyping. Even if some vague googling finds me an answer to question 1, i'm usually at a loss for step 2. Note: I would require shipping to Australia.

Right now I am looking for a solution to supply 2 x 3-5A @ 5v from 2 x ~3.3-4.2V sources or 6-10A @ 5V from a ~6.6-8.4V source (powering some WS2812B LED's from 18650 batteries - not a terribly uncommon task I would think). My only tighter requirement is that it be able to fit within a 18mm ID tube - given the current (A) requirements I understand this may not necessarily be achievable, in which case the diameter will grow as necessary, though I would like to attempt to meet it if I can. If anyone knows a solution to this specific problem, I'm very happy to hear it. Though in the interest of teach a man to fish... I'm seeking the tools to do my own research (not least of all because the above requirements are still subject to change).

Comment: First, you will have to decide what you are going to design. That is up to you. For selection, the likes of [Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/) will order whole families of searches about any way you like. And most parts are available in one piece quantities.

Comment: I second that, first action is to search distributors's databases. It makes no sense to plan with parts that are widely unavailable. Most headaches: connectors.

Comment: Voting to close on the basis that the question encourages opinions. There is also an underlying shopping question. Ask a straightforward question to get a (reaonably) straightforward answer.

Comment: @Andyaka "Ask a straightforward question to get a (reaonably) straightforward answer." Granted it's a non-technical question but it read a perfectly straightforward as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four basic criteria that a chip must meet to be selected for a design:

1. Functional Specifications
2. Physical Specifications
3. Low Cost
4. Good Availability

You can use the parametric search at the various distributors like [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/) and [Mouser](http://mouser.com) to find parts that meet all of these criteria.  Individual manufacturers also usually have parametric search functions at their websites, but the distributors allow you to compare between different manufacturers.  After a while, you start to learn which manufacturers have the most competitive parts in various categories.  The distributor parametric searches also allow you to limit the search to specific manufacturers, only parts that are in stock, sort by selected parameters, specific packages, etc.  It makes part selection much easier.

For a regulator search for example, you would first get to the regulator portion of the distributor's site and the specify ranges for voltages and current to see a selection of devices that meet your specs.

For parts with easily searchable characteristics, you can also often just google parametric requirements like [10A Buck Regulator](https://www.google.com/search?q=10A%20buck%20regulator) and find promising parts.

Just like distributors allow you to search across manufacturers, once you have decided on a particular part, you can use [findchips.com](https://www.findchips.com/) to search for the best price and availability across all of the distributors.  When you are actually purchasing parts, findchips.com saves a HUGE amount of time.

As for the specific case of the part that you are looking for, high current boost (voltage increase) converters are harder to find than high current buck (voltage decrease) converters.  In terms of power density, it's hard to beat Linear Technology [µModule Regulators.](http://www.linear.com/products/umodule_regulators)

Keep in mind that even with a 90% efficient supply you are looking at dissipating 5W (10% of 10A * 5V) in a very small space.  I hope that the tube is metal and you can thermally connect the regulator to it, or that the regulator doesn't have to run continuously.

Comment: +1. This is exactly how I do these things. I only prefer Digikey for better and more reasonable parametrics. Mouser is catching up lately, but still...

Comment: I agree that Digikey's parametrics are better.  I also like that Digikey can ship light weight orders via first class mail, saving a lot on shipping.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 How do you research and select a chip for a given task? one focus is the ERROR BUDGET

Suppose you want 0.01% measurement accuracy of some sensor voltage. That is 100 PPM total error; Does temperature changes enter this error? Will you place the system inside a controlled-temp box?

Suppose the sensor is a bridge of strain gauges, and ratiometric performance is expected, thus the exact VREF does not matter. But the VREF is pulled from the VDD, and VDD has 0.1 volt spikes because VDD comes from a switch-reg with spikes and ripple. Can you establish an ERROR BUDGET?